# Яндекс.Карты. Как запретить скрытие hint и его перемещение вслед за курсором

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Как контролировать поведение hint?

**Задача.**

Использую кластеризацию. Необходимо всегда показывать hint всех объкетов-кластеров. На самом деле задача - показывать над каждой иконкой кластера статичный тултип с количеством точек кластера, но кроме как хинт среди стандартных инструментов я не нашел более подходящего. Возможно балун, но там есть свои нюансы.

**Проблемы.**

1. хинт показывается только один и при попытке открывать их перебором
   открыт будет только последний
2. хинт меняет положение в зависимости от положения курсора мыши -
   двигается вслед за ним
3. хинт закрывается после ухода курсора с метки объекта-кластера
4. хинт нужно спозиционировать относительно метки кластера, так как у кластеров метки разного размера в зависимости от количества
   объединенных точек

Как пытался решить.

Пытался отслеживать события мыши на объекте clusterer и на map вплоть до радикальных методов типа:

```
clusterer.events.add(
  ['mouseleave', 'mouseenter', 'mousemove'],
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  },
    true
);
```

Comment: Зачем вы создали метку [яндекс.карты]? Есть уже [яндекс-карты]. Они ничем не отличаются!

Comment: Метку [яндекс] вообще использовать не надо.